# Check wordpress shortcode is exists on home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

Is there any way to know specific shortcode is applied on specific page?

for e.g. On any WP Theme's home page if related_products shortcode is applied then I want to check it in my plugin file that is applied or not?
Is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`has_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode) to check if your shortcode is applied. If you need to specifically check if it is used on the home page, you can add the `is_home()` check

```
global $post;
if( is_home() && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'related_products') ) {
    echo "YEAH, shortcode is applied on home page";
}else{
    echo "Houston, we have a problem!!!";
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Let me explain. I have an index.php file which has following shortcode do_shortcode( '[recent_products per_page="12" columns="3"]' ); and I want to check in my plugin Is this shortcode is applied on home page?

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: See my update, and please explain what does not working means, are you getting errors, is nothing dispayed, what exactly is not working